# can a "let" statement define 2+ things

Tags: javascript

Recently I've discovered a problem in my code that I needed 2 different things defined by "args." I've removed the code and don't quite remember any more, but would there be a way to do something like:

```
let args = "v1," "v2"
```

Or is this just a stupid question?
I'd also like to know the same for things like const and var.

Comment: Yes, you can declare multiple variables, you just don't need quotes. `let foo = 5, bar = 7` -- you can also declare them without definition: `let foo, bar`

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: `let args = "v1", anotherArgs="v2"` if you need two variables; `let args = ["v1", "v2"]` if you need args as an array of values

Comment: @IvanBacher, new to js, will loook into it though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle that would be to put the data into the array like so:

```
let args = ["v1", "v2"];
```

And you can acess the values like so :

```
args[0]; // v1
args[1]; // v2
```

It that what you were looking for ?

Comment: I think so. So if I were to do:
```isNaN(args[0])``` it would use ```v1``` and ```isNaN(args[1])``` it would use ```v2```? And does this go the same for const and var?

Comment: Thx! You too :)